# Static variable value lost in IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I'm using a Webservice coded in C# using .Net Framework 3.5.

The WebMethods of this Webservice besides their main workload also connect to Salesforce to retrieve and write data, so I'm using a static variable for keeping the Salesforce api login object alive between requests, this way I only log in once (on Salesforce) and then reuse this variable for subsequent calls, avoiding the need to login on each request.

This static object is evaluated on the main ctor of the Webservice, to check if some properties inside the login object are valid (for example, the validity of the session), if not, the login method is called again.

This works with no problems at all on my development environment (Windows 7 and VS2012 IIS7.5? Dev server) and in a test server (Win Server 2003, IIS6), but it doesn't work at all on the production box which is also a Windows Server 2003 with IIS6, because the static variable value is null on each request, logging in Salesforce on every request, giving long response times for each call and also hitting some limits on Salesforce, locking the account and blocking any following logins.

Sadly both machines (test and production) don't have the same configuration and the production box is currently unreachable for me, so the recycling time of the App Pool and other specifics are unknown to me at the moment.

I think this is a configuration issue, but anyway here is my code, firstly i started only by having a static variable inside the Webservice main class and then (current version) creating a whole static class with static variables.

All of the following code is under the same namespace

Static class (Salesforce login logic):

```
public static class Srv
{
    public static SFHelpers helper = new SFHelpers(); // own class, Holds Salesforce logic and data related to this requirement
    public static SforceService SFserv = new SforceService(); // Salesforce class that handles login (and other Salesforce data manipulation methods)
    public static DateTime NextLoginSF = DateTime.MinValue; // Determines when does the Salesforce session expires

    public static void LoginSalesforce()
    { // Simplified salesforce login steps, removed try-catch and other conditions to facilitate comprehension
        SFserv.Url = helper.URLSalesforce;
        LoginResult loginResult = SFserv.login(SFuser, SFpass);
        NextLoginSF = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(loginResult.userInfo.sessionSecondsValid);
        SFserv.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
        SFserv.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader { sessionId = loginResult.sessionId };
    }
}
```

Main ctor and sample Webmethod:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://helloSO.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WsSFTest : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public WsSFTest()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Srv.SFserv.SessionHeaderValue == null || DateTime.Now >= Srv.NextLoginSF) // any of this will trigger a login to renew Salesforce session
            {
                Srv.LoginSalesforce();
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException se)
        {
            if (se.Code.Name == ExceptionCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID.ToString())
            { // Login again because Salesforce invalidated my session somehow 
                Srv.LoginSalesforce();
            }
            else
            {
                // Irrelevant
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Irrelevant
        }
    }

[WebMethod]
    public SampleResult SampleMethod(int param)
    {
        try
        {
            //irrelevant code gathers values here
            var something = Srv.helper.Method(param, anotherParam);    
            return something;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Irrelevant
        }
    }
}
```

Serializing the login object to a local file or persistance database are my last options since quick response times are a must.

I think what's left for me to try are Session variables but given this behavior odds that something similar could happen seem high.

Any clues? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the end I realized some evaluation value in this line (Specifically Srv.NextLoginSF)

```
if (Srv.SFserv.SessionHeaderValue == null || DateTime.Now >= Srv.NextLoginSF) // any of this will trigger a login to renew Salesforce session
```

Was returning with a different value than expected, and that the static variable wasn't losing its value